# $\ker\left(T\right)\cap\text{Im}\left(T\right)=\left\{ 0\right\}$ iff $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\ker\left(T\right)+\text{Im}\left(T\right) $ .

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to prove the following claim: 
Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  be a linear transformation. Then $\ker\left(T\right)\cap\text{Im}\left(T\right)=\left\{ 0\right\}$ 
  iff $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\ker\left(T\right)+\text{Im}\left(T\right)$. The if part was easy but for some reason I can't manage to show the only if. Help would be appreciated.

**Proof of if direction:** Proof. Let $U\subseteq\ker\left(T\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  and $V\subseteq\text{Im}\left(T\right)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  be a basis for $\ker\left(T\right)$
  and $\text{Im}\left(T\right)$
  respectively. Since $\ker\left(A\right)\cap\text{Im}\left(T\right)=\left\{ 0\right\}$
  no non-trivial vector in $\text{Im}\left(A\right)$
  can be expressed as a linear combination of vector in $U$
  and likewise no vector in $\text{Im}\left(T\right)$
  can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $V$
  and thus $U$
  is linearly independent of $V$
 . Furthermore by the rank-nullity theorem $$\left|U\right|+\left|V\right|=\text{dim}\left(\ker\left(T\right)\right)+\text{dim}\left(\text{Im}\left(T\right)\right)=\dim\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$$
 So $U\cup V$
  is a set of $n$
  linearly independent vectors and thus a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
 . This of course implies that every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
  can be expressed as a unique linear combination of vectors in $U\cup V$
  and in particular as a unique sum of two vectors in $\text{span}U=\ker\left(T\right)$
  and $\text{span}V=\text{Im}\left(T\right)$
  proving that $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\ker\left(T\right)\oplus\text{Im}\left(T\right)$
 .

Comment: Perhaps include your proof for the only-if direction in your question? It might itself contain a hint for the if direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the Grassmann formula
$$
\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim U_1+\dim U_2+\dim(U_1\cap U_2)
$$
and the rank nullity theorem
$$
\dim\ker T+\dim\operatorname{Im}T = n
$$
then you're done.